# Handle ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Devise registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

My users table has unique indexes on the email and username fields. Every now and then the uniqueness constraint will be broken, and a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception will be thrown. It can happen due to a race condition in the rails uniqueness validation, when the user submits the registration form twice in rapid succession, or when two users attempt to register with the same username, at the same time.

When the exception is caused by two successive registration requests I would like to sign the user in. Otherwise, when the uniqueness constraint is broken by the rare case of two users registering with the same username, I'd like to display the usual "taken" error.

To do so I've overridden the create action:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    begin
      super
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
      if user.present? && user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
        # The credentials are valid for the existing user. We can
        # sign them in.
        sign_in(:user, user)
        respond_with user, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(user)
      else
        # The credentials are invalid.
        # This should only happen if multiple users register with the
        # same email at the same time. Now we can simply attempt to
        # register the user again, knowing it will fail, in order to
        # generate the appropriate error messages.
        super
      end
    end        
  end
end
```

Is there a way to make Devise handle `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exceptions and achieve something similar to what I have done?

Comment: What version of Devise are you using?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.

The exception is thrown  because of the `add_index :email, unique => true`, added by devise to your user model (have a look in your migrations). This adds a uniqueness constraint at database level, overriding frameowrk validations.

Actually i decided to throw off the uniqueness of the email index, so that i can manage everything with rails validations, but i actually don't know if it's completely correct, nor if it supposed to work this way as it's the first time i'm using devise with STI.

hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, the unique index was not added by devise. I added it myself. The built in rails uniqueness validations are good enough for most sites, but with enough requests you will start experiencing duplicates because of a race condition. In short, the time between rails having determined that the new row is unique, and the row being inserted into the database, is sometimes enough for another request with the same "unique" values to come in, in which case it will also be treated as unique by rails (remember that the first row is not inserted into the database yet). Both rows end up being saved.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `:validatable` in your resource model. Most likely in `user.rb`. It should look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable, 
         :trackable,
         :validatable
end
```

> Make sure `:validatable` is included. Or else it won't capture the errors from database.